# How to use ContentResolver openFileDescriptor to get the same result?

Tags: android, file, download, filepath

a view weeks ago I finished this small project witch downloads a file from the web tot the phone and the opens it directly. All worked perfect until new Android release was done "7 Nougat".

Now the application is closed because of deprecated function witch I use to get the path of the file.

```
int fileNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
String savedFilePath = cursor.getString(fileNameIndex);
```

The application metions that I need to use:

```
ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()
```

I have tried several things, but I didn't manage to get it to work.

The code I now use for downloading a file from a url. If somebody can help me out, I would really appreciated your time en effort to help me out!

```
    if((Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment() != null && Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment().endsWith(".pdf"))){

        this.viewShowFile = view.getContext();


        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        final String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        request.setDescription("Download Montageblad");
        request.setTitle(fileName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(view.getContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);


        receiverNotificationClicked = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                String extraId = DownloadManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_CLICK_DOWNLOAD_IDS;

                long[] references = intent.getLongArrayExtra(extraId);

                for (long reference : references ){
                    if(reference == downloadReference){
                        // Do something here ?
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        view.getContext().registerReceiver(receiverNotificationClicked,filter);


        receiverDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {



            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                if(downloadReference == reference){
                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(reference);
                    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);

                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

                    int fileNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
                    String savedFilePath = cursor.getString(fileNameIndex);
                    //Log.i("saved path",savedFilePath);

                    int mimtypeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE);
                    String mimType = cursor.getString(mimtypeIndex);


                    switch (status){
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                            Toast.makeText( context ,"DOWNLOAD READY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            File file = new File(savedFilePath);

                            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimType);
                            target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                            Intent intentFile = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open bestand");
                            try {
                                NavigationHandler.this.viewShowFile.startActivity(intentFile);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
                                Toast.makeText( context ,"File could not be opend!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                            Toast.makeText( context ,"DOWNLOAD FAILD!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                        case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                            Toast.makeText( context ,"DOWNLOAD START!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        view.getContext().registerReceiver(receiverDownloadComplete,intentFilter);
```

**SOLUTION**: I solved the problem by using the "DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI" witch returns the path to the file. However the path starts with "file://". When I replaced "file://" with nothing it contains a relative path to the file witch then can be opend from the device.

```
savedFilePath = savedFilePath.replace("file://","");
```

Comment: get the `Uri` by calling `DownloadManager#getUriForDownloadedFile()` (or column `COLUMN_LOCAL_URI` / `COLUMN_MEDIAPROVIDER_URI`)

Comment: Ow thanks mate this works for me :).

Comment: what solution? getUriForDownloadedFile? or reading the column? if so, which column?

Comment: Ok I was a bit to fast with my conclusion "COLUMN_LOCAL_URI" works to not let the app crash. It also downloads the file but now when the file done downloading it gives me a popup to open it directly in a pdf viewer. There it says that it can't open the file probably because path is still incorrect to open it!

Comment: try `ContentResolver#openInputStream` and read some few first bytes and see what you get there

Comment: Ok so where do i place this code ? I'm new to Android development so sorry for not understanding directly what you  mean.

Comment: inside `onReceive` when you got the "download complete" broadcast - the first 5 bytes should be `%PDF-`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142060/discussion-between-iason-and-pskink).

Comment: Ok so I manage to solf the problem. By using "DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI" and then I replaced from the path name the "file://" with nothing, so now it only returns the relative path witch can be opend.

Comment: Great! This solutions works for me but omitting the string replace.